# What does the pointer value of a function pointer represent?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Trying to understand what the pointer to function actually represent? Is it the address in the code segment where the function resides?

For ex: this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    printf("a's address: %p\n", &a);
    printf("foo's address: %p\n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

... prints this:

```
[sh/prog-exercises/adam]:./a.out 
a's address: 0xbfffb414 
foo's address: 0x8048430
```

I guess I am a little confused with how exactly stack/heap of a process relates with the ELF data-segment/code-segment. Any helpful pointers would be really welcome. Also, my first question, so please be gentle, am really trying to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the address of the function entry point - start of its code. The `a` variable is located on stack, so no surprise its address differs significantly - stack and code are assigned different code regions taht can be quite far apart.

Comment: Right, so the output here represents the location where this particular function has been loaded as part of the code-segment? Is there a way for a C program to print the data segment, code segment begin/end addresses?

Comment: @helpmelearn: Yes, that's the address where the function start is located. I'm not aware of a solution for finding the segments addresses and I suppose it would be implementation-dependent. Perhaps there's some utility program that can do this for just any process.

Answer (score 3):

This image from the book **[UNIX: Systems Programming](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0130424110/ch02lev1sec3)** should make things clear.

At the bottom of the diagram, you have your program text (low addresses). As can be verified from your program. That's where foo() would reside.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is that your code is not entirely standards compliant.  If you use gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ansi you will get a complaint about the line where you are printing the function pointer.  This is because the standard does not guarantee that function pointers can be converted to void pointers.  C is designed to work on many different architectures, and if the architecture is a Harvard architecture (separate instruction and data memory) there might be good reasons to make these pointers different sizes.

I guess that in practice it is not likely to matter, but a good factoid to be aware of.  Esp when you are trying to learn the intimate details of C.